# Batch Render Heightmaps and Save Image

Tags: scripting, height-map

I would like to use Blender to sequentially render 10,000+ height maps applied to a displacement mesh, save the image with a serialized filename, and move on to the next height map.  I can do them individually by manually updating the image texture source in the Blender file, but an automated process would be preferable.

Any recommendations on where to look, what I should be looking for, or how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: If said maps are properly named as a singe consistent series you can add them an image sequence to an animated displacement modifier map. Then just render them as a regular animation